# How can I make only one column of a table selectable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I prevent the user from highlighting one column in a table?

I have a 2-column table. Users will want to copy the content in the second column, but not the first column.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>line1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>line2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>line3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a JSFiddle with an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vepq0e29/

When the user copies and pastes, I want the output to just be:
line1
line2
line3
...
line7

I don't want col1 to show up or be highlighted when the user selects the table.

How can I make it so that users can only select and copy content from the second column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use pseudo-elements to show the text. Text from pseudo-elements is never copied at the moment (not sure, if it'll be changed sometime).

http://jsfiddle.net/vepq0e29/3/

```css
td:first-child:after {
    content: attr(aria-label);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td aria-label="col1"></td>
        <td>line1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td aria-label="col1"></td>
        <td>line2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td aria-label="col1"></td>
        <td>line3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td aria-label="col1"></td>
        <td>line4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td aria-label="col1"></td>
        <td>line5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td aria-label="col1"></td>
        <td>line6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td aria-label="col1"></td>
        <td>line7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tr td:first-child {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */      
}
```

The user can't select the first column as long as he is not viewing the html source code.
http://jsfiddle.net/vepq0e29/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While the first column isn't highlighted, if I copy and paste, the first column still shows up when I paste.

Comment: Wrong. You don't allow to start or end the selection inside of first column. But if you select a few lines and copy them, the first column will be there too.

Comment: You are right, I just checked if i can select it but not what happens when you copy it.

Comment: This behaviour seems to be browser dependant: just tried it and with latest versions: Chrome and IE will paste the first column, but Firefox not. FireFox and Chrome will not hightlight first column, IE will...

Comment: @Qwertiy you found the best solution best solution by using css

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this example, try yourself use **Run Cde Snippet** below and just select all rows in single column and then copy and paste in any editor and see results :)

Hope this will help

```css
div.table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
div.td-outer {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #00aaff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
div.tr {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 140px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.td-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 90%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 95%;
  margin: 3px;
}
div.td-inner span {
  height: 95%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="td-outer">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td-inner"> <span>
            col1
                    </span>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td-inner"> <span>
     col1
        </span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="td-outer">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td-inner"> <span>
        line1
        </span>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td-inner"> <span>
        line2
        </span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```